# Add a UIButton to navigationBar of RootViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, swift2, uiwindow

I am new to swift, On click of a push notification, I am trying to open a VC , here is the code

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main",bundle: nil)

        let detailVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DetailsViewController") as! DetailsViewController

        detailVC.eventId = eventId

        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController:detailVC)


                let myButton = UIButton()
                myButton.titleLabel!.frame = CGRectMake(15, 54, 300, 500)
                myButton.titleLabel!.text = "Button Label"
                myButton.titleLabel!.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
                myButton.titleLabel!.textAlignment = .Center
              navigationController.navigationBar.addSubview(myButton)

        self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
```

Now the VC opens with navigationBar on top, But I dont see any button added. So I want to know is where I am going wrong.

Based on @Hugo reponse

I updated the code in viewDidLoad

```
let btnName = UIButton()
        //btnName.setImage(UIImage(named: "imagename"), forState: .Normal)
        btnName.titleLabel?.text = "Test"
        btnName.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        btnName.frame = CGRectMake(0, 30, 30, 30)
        btnName.addTarget(self, action: Selector("action"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        //.... Set Right/Left Bar Button item
        let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem()
        rightBarButton.customView = btnName

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
```

but still no luck

Regards
Ranjit

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't add subviews directly to a `UINavigationBar` instead you should be using the [UINavigationItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/) of the view controller and setting the `leftBarButtonItem` or `rightBarButtonItem`.

In your case you should be adding the bar button items in `viewDidLoad:` of your `DetailsViewController`.

**Example:**

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = instanceOfUIBarButtonItem
```

Comment: Hello @Hugo Tunius thanks. I tried your logic, but I dont see any button

Comment: You can't use `UIButton` needs to be a `UIBarButtonItem`

Comment: Have you tried using just a regular bar button item? Like the `initWithTitle:style:target:action:` another option is trying the customView constructor and instead of the property

Comment: Do you really need a UIButton customView? A UIBarButtonItem is already a kind of button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104889/discussion-between-ranjit-and-hugo-tunius).